# How to run a java program on multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Below is my code to extract text from a text file and displaying it on the console.

Could some one please tell me how to make this program run on multiple threads simultaneoulsly?

I would also like to know if multiple threads are being used in performing the task as the time taken to run the task is varied every time i run.??

```
    //Code    
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;


    class Extract{
    static int i=0;
    FileInputStream in;
    BufferedReader br;
    ArrayList<String> stringList;
    String li; 


    Extract() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
     FileInputStream in = new  FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\sputta\\workspace\\Sample\\src\\threads.txt");
     br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
     stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
     li=" ";
    }

    void call() 
    {
    try{
    while(li!=null)
    {
    String str = br.readLine();
    stringList.add(str);
    li=stringList.get(i);
    if(li!=null)
    {
    System.out.println(li);
    i++;
    }
    } 
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    in.close();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println(e);
    }
    }
    }

    class Caller implements Runnable {

       Extract target;
       Thread t;
       public Caller(Extract targ) 
       {
       target = targ;
       t = new Thread(this);
       t.start();
       System.out.println(t.isAlive());
       }

       public void run() 
       {
        synchronized(target) { // synchronized block
        target.call();   
       }
      }
    }

    public class Sample {
       public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
       {
         long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         System.out.println(startTime);
         Extract target = new Extract();
         Caller ob1 = new Caller(target);
         Caller ob2 = new Caller(target);
         Caller ob3 = new Caller(target);

         try {
              ob1.t.join();
              ob2.t.join();
              ob3.t.join();
              }

        catch(InterruptedException e)
             {
               System.out.println("Interrupted");
             }
           }
         }
```

Comment: Read the Java Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: Do you want to read multiple files from different threads, or a single file? If it's a single file, that's much harder and isn't likely to give any performance improvement due to being IO-bound.

Comment: What's your end goal in doing this?

Comment: Concurrent file parsing is a much harder problem that just spinning up multiple threads.

Comment: @JonSkeet I would like to extract from a single large file with as min time as possible

Comment: @seand i need to extract text from large sized text file and at a higher speed.This is not the actual code.Its just a prototype.

Comment: @Saikiran: Well if you're IO-bound (i.e. the time taken is really the time to read the data) then adding multiple threads won't help. If you're doing something computationally expensive with each line, that's a different matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you Jon.and do i need to go with existing code without any additions (i.e.,threads)?? Or is there anyother solution for the problem that could do it in min time possible??

Comment: Well you need to give us more *context* - and ideally tell us what you've already tried, as well as what profiling you've performed to find the bottleneck. (It could be that the existing code is too slow because it's written inefficiently.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I just replaced the above code with my actual code.Could you please have a look at it??

sorry in a hurry.so the code formatting is not good.sorry for the inconvenience

Thanks

Comment: With all the commented out lines and badly formatted code, I'm afraid I'm not prepared to go through that carefully to check for performance problems. The fact that you're in a hurry doesn't make the code any easier to read. I strongly suspect that you'll find if you present your code cleanly, you'll actually get an answer more quickly...

Comment: But the fact that you have multiple threads all of which synchronize on the same object for the entirety of their `run` method means that you're *effectively* running the code in series, not in parallel... but making your life vastly more complicated in order to do so.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank you so much for your suggestions.I would now try for an alternative. Thank u all :)

Answer (score 2):

It does not make much sense performance-wise to have multiple threads reading from the same file, due to the inevitable input/output (`I/O`) bottleneck.

Two things that can be done to improve the situation:

1. "Split" the file into smaller pieces and assign each such "split" to a different thread. This is the approach followed by `Hadoop`, but it does require copying each "split" before processing, so it is only beneficial for large files (say, at least 100 MB each, or much more).
2. Use 1 thread to read from the file into a "prefetch" buffer, in memory, and then process the input from the buffer, via multiple other threads. A variation of this approach would be for the prefetch thread to "feed" each of the "consumer" threads with data, before each of them starts. Obviously, the relative allocation of prefetch vs. processing across the threads, will yield varying results, so further tuning would be necessary, depending on the application.

Both approaches have limitations and do not guarantee performance improvements in all cases.

Reading a text file line-by-line from a single thread can be done at a speed of over 1 million lines/sec, but still the bottleneck will remain in `I/O`, as already discussed.

Comment: I would add that the "split" trick is only useful if the split is made accross different hardware ! There's no point splitting on the same hard drive.

Comment: Correct, unless you copy each split to a separate file, which (as already discussed) is meaningful only for large files. :-)